# AWS Lambda's callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop in C# SDK

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

According to Mongo Atlas integration with AWS's best practices page, AWS Lambda's `callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop`'s value should be set to `false` but I can't find this property in .NET SDK.

Is this specific to NodeJS or is it available in .NET too?

Comment: You mean [here](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/best-practices-connecting-to-aws-lambda/) I presume, and you really should include any links you refer to within your question. If you read the page it's quite clearly NodeJS specific. If you [read the linked article on that page](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/optimizing-aws-lambda-performance-with-mongodb-atlas-and-nodejs) it's not only clearly about NodeJS, but mentions various sections about where they apply to "general" best practices for any language and which are all about NodeJS and the implementation on AWS Lambda.

Comment: The callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop property is specific to the NodeJS Context object.

Answer (score 1):

The `context` given to each lambda function is specific to each language ([You can read about the C# one here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/dotnet-context-object.html)).

`callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop` is unique to NodeJS, because of the various ways lambda can detects that a node handler has completed and is returning a response. In the case of Atlas' best practice, this is suggested because if you use the persistent scope outside the handler to pool a connection between invocations, lambda will halt waiting for the socket to close (empty the event loop).e

.NET [has its own way](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/dotnet-programming-model-handler-types.html#dot-net-async) of explicitly determining when to return.

Comment: Does that mean that there's no handle on the persistent scope that handles the mongo connection pool in .NET as there is in NodeJS? Is it on by default in .NET?

Comment: You should be able to do it, by taking the connection outside the handler scope (e.g. making it a global). I've found mixed reports of this working, however- depending on how well the library you're using supports the connection freezing the lambda does. Typically the pattern is to check if you have still have a live connection, but be prepared to set one up if the thawed connection cannot re-establish (e.g. it could have timed out on the other end)